# Ruby 1.9.3 - Net::IMAP list and status methods response very slow

Tags: imap, ruby-1.9.3

Using **Ruby 1.9.3p0**

Below is my ruby script to display, from my GMail account, all folders' 
name and the messages count in each mailbox.

**Ruby Script**

```
    ENV['SSL_CERT_FILE']='/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem'

    begin_ = Time.now

    require 'net/imap'

    server='imap.gmail.com'
    port = 993
    username = '<MY-GMAIL-USER-ID>'
    password = '<MY-PASSWORD>'

    imap = Net::IMAP.new(server,port,true)
    imap.login(username, password)

    list = imap.list("", "*")

    puts "Gathering Data"

    folders_count_hash = Hash[ list.map do |a|
                                    [a.name, imap.status(a.name, ["MESSAGES"])["MESSAGES"]] unless a.name == "[Gmail]"   
                               end ]

    total_time = Time.now - begin_
    puts "Gathered Data"                           
    puts "Total Folders :#{folders_count_hash.size}"
    puts "RUNTIME: #{total_time}"

    folders_count_hash.each do |name, count| 
       puts "#{name} (#{count})"
    end

    imap.logout()
    imap.disconnect()
```

Output of the above script:

```
    Gathering Data
    Gathered Data
    Total Folders :193
    RUNTIME: 189.38250329
```

*As can be seen from the output's RUNTIME value it took 3 minutes to gather the data.*

I need to understand what is reason behind such slow behavior.
Is it because of so many folders in my account or due to network speed or from GMail's end in returning the response?

Can this delay be reduced? If yes, then how can I achieve the same.

Thanks,

Jignesh

Comment: Having a very similar problem...

Comment: Try telnet (openssl for gmail)

    openssl s_client -connect imap.gmail.com:993
    x login <login> <password>
    x list "" "*"
    x logout

Answer (score 0):

I run that code and get a response in 11 seconds, but I only have 39 folders.